# How to fix jquery on popup

Tags: jquery, wordpress

here is the image that i'm trying to fix when I hover on the first share icon the popup menu is showing also on other share instances how do i prevent this?

[image]

here is the full code base on the [TNW Social Count](https://github.com/thenextweb/TNW-Social-Count)

```
var TNWSC = {
    init: function () {
        var t;
        var autohide = true;
        jQuery(
            '.tooltip-wrapper, #sharing-widget'
        )
            .hover(function () {
                clearTimeout(t);
                TNWSC.show_tooltip(
                    true);
                autohide = true;
            }, function () {
                if (autohide ===
                    true) {
                    t = setTimeout(
                        "TNWSC.show_tooltip(false)",
                        800);
                }
            });

        jQuery('#tooltip-close')
            .click(function () {
                clearTimeout(t);
                TNWSC.show_tooltip(
                    false);
                autohide = true;
            });

        jQuery(".popup-link")
            .click(function (e) {
                TNWSC.open_popup($(
                        this)
                    .attr("href"));
                e.preventDefault();
            });
    },

    show_tooltip: function (show) {
        if (show) {
            jQuery('.icon-share')
                .addClass('active');
            jQuery('.tooltip-wrapper')
                .show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.icon-share')
                .removeClass('active');
            jQuery('.tooltip-wrapper')
                .hide();
        }
    },

    open_popup: function (url) {

        var width = 640;
        var height = 420;
        var popupName = 'popup_' +
            width + 'x' + height;

        var left = (screen.width -
            width) / 2;
        var top = ((screen.height -
            height) / 2) + 25;
        var params = 'width=' + width +
            ',height=' + height +
            ',location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,left=' +
            left + ',top=' + top;

        window[popupName] = window.open(
            url, popupName, params);

        if (window.focus) {
            window[popupName].focus();
        }
    }

};

jQuery(document)
    .ready(function () {
        TNWSC.init();
    });
```

Comment: this is the a plugin for wordpress https://github.com/thenextweb/TNW-Social-Count I think this is only applicable for single page but when I put it on the homepage that error occure where when I hover it popups all the share button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you pass a reference to the hovered element to your `show_tooltip` function. Then, select the elements *within that element* that you'd like to `show()` or `addclass()`.

Something like this for your `hover()`:

```
TNWSC.show_tooltip(true,jQuery(this));
```

Then something like this for `show_tooltip`:

```
show_tooltip: function(show,$obj) {
    if(show) {
        jQuery('.icon-share',$obj).addClass('active');
        jQuery('.tooltip-wrapper',$obj).show();      
    } else {
        jQuery('.icon-share',$obj).removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.tooltip-wrapper',$obj).hide();      
    }
}
```

Please find two examples in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qFR27/). The first one is like yours in that **all** elements turn on and off if you hover over only **one** of them. The second example uses `jQuery(this)` to reference the object over which the mouse is hovering.

I may be able to get more specific to your code if you are able to include your relevant HTML.

---

### Edit:

Thanks for the jsFiddle.

Below are modified sections of your code. Notice that the `$hovered` object is passed to `show_tooltip()` so that it knows which box is active.

The timeouts that close the boxes are set based on the DOM index of the active element and are stored separately in an array. That way, the two timeouts function independently from one another.

```
var t=[];
var autohide = true;

jQuery('.toolbar-social').hover(function () {
    var $hovered=jQuery(this);
    clearTimeout(t[$hovered.index()]);
    TNWSC.show_tooltip(true, $hovered);
    autohide = true;
}, function () {
    if (autohide === true) {
       var $hovered=jQuery(this);
       t[$hovered.index()] = setTimeout(function() {TNWSC.show_tooltip(false,$hovered)}, 800);
    }
});
```

I changed `#tooltip-close` to a class rather than an ID, because we want more than one of them on the page:

```
jQuery('.tooltip-close').click(function () {
    var $hovered=jQuery(this).closest('.toolbar-social');
    clearTimeout(t[$hovered.index()]);
    TNWSC.show_tooltip(false,$hovered);
    autohide = true;
});
```

And here's the `show_tooltip()` function, using the `$hovered` object again to modify only child elements of the active box.

```
show_tooltip: function (show, $hovered) {
    if (show) {
        jQuery('.icon-share',$hovered).addClass('active');
        jQuery('.tooltip-wrapper',$hovered).show();
    } else {
        jQuery('.icon-share',$hovered).removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.tooltip-wrapper',$hovered).hide();
    }
},
```

Here's a [working example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/HhpbV/3/).

Comment: That code contains PHP and will not function on jsFiddle. If possible, please use the rendered HTML code rather than the PHP source.

Comment: here is the updated one sorry if it's quite messy http://jsfiddle.net/psc20/HhpbV/1/

Comment: wow! thank you very much I also update the 800 to 100 because it's quite slow to remove the box :) thanks for the help much appreciated and also thanks for the great explanation